# Convert Hex (bytes) to ASCII text in Odd-length string

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I am trying to write converter that will accept any length Hex (bytes) to ASCII text. This one online works great

https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html

However when I am trying to do:
`binascii.unhexlify(data).decode('utf8')` 
its 
giving me error: Odd-length string. or `binascii.a2b_hex(data[:8])` 
(Non-hexadecimal digit found)

And yes I have tried to `strip()` but it still giving this error

```
import binascii

text ="""
20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 50 6C 75 6E 67 65 72 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 38 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4F 63 63 6C 75 73 69 6F 6E 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 38 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 43 6C 61 6D 70 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 39 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4D 65 64 69 61 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 39 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4D 65 64 69 61 45 6E 67 69 6E 65 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 34 33 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 49 6E 66 75 73 69 6F 6E 45 6E 67 69 6E 65 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 34 36 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 43 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 9F 60 02 06 00 D6 94 04 00 00
"""

new = binascii.a2b_hex(text.strip())
print(new)
```

So I tried to convert it char by char like this, But I cant put those codes into text...

```
import binascii

file = "secret.bin"
decoded =  []

with open(file, "rb") as file:
    data = file.read()
    hex_list = data.split(" ")

ascii_data = [ binascii.b2a_hex(i) for i in hex_list] 

print(ascii_data)
```

Comment: You have told us what you are trying to do and one of your difficulties. But just what is your question to us?

Comment: Is this approach of doing this char by char is correctly? And how do do it, because I cant make use of those ascii codes. When I paste codes here: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/ its nonsense

Comment: And generally the point is, how to convert this hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Odd-length string` error by removing the spaces from the `text`:

```
import binascii

text = """\
20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 50 6C 75 6E 67 65 72 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 38 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4F 63 63 6C 75 73 69 6F 6E 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 38 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 43 6C 61 6D 70 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 39 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4D 65 64 69 61 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 31 39 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 4D 65 64 69 61 45 6E 67 69 6E 65 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 34 33 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 49 6E 66 75 73 69 6F 6E 45 6E 67 69 6E 65 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 61 74 65 3A 20 33 0A 53 59 53 20 54 69 6D 65 3A 20 32 34 36 2C 20 74 61 73 6B 3A 20 43 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 20 67 6F 74 20 73 74 9F 60 02 06 00 D6 94 04 00 00\
"""

new = binascii.a2b_hex(text.replace(' ',''))
print(new)
```

Also, because you define the `text` variable on three lines without `\` you get an `\n` in your hex string, that is the reason that you get the `Non-hexadecimal digit found` error. Either use `\` at the end of the line or define text on one line.